# Adapt iPhone 8 To iPhone 8 plus

Tags: xcode, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am trying to make an app that looks the same on modern iPhone models but the screen of the iPhone 8 plus looks different from the iPhone 8 when running the app.

[iPhone 8 and 8 plus models running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xTD4.png)

How can I make the green bar of the iPhone 8 look the same as the one in the 8 plus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a library called layouthelper that can customize constraints for different iPhone sizes.